# "grab" Post form response with php (response is a txt file)

Tags: php, file, post, text-files

I have a form that posts a file to a site that I don't have control and that site responds with a dynamically generated text file based on the uploaded file. That response is downloaded by the client after the form is submitted. My question is: **how can I grab this text file and copy it to my server before it gets to the user**?

Possible solution 1: is there a way to change this file's headers and put its content to some hidden div or iframe?

Possible solution 2: I think the best way is that I create a script that gets the form data and then reposts it to the external site and then gets the response and writes this response to my site in a txt file. Unfortunately all my attempts to get this working have failed.

Example of solution 2:

```
<form action="mysite.com/respostScriptThatGrabsResponse.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="filename"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</from>
```

Comment: So, you want to intercept the data between your site and the external site?

Comment: You could upload the file to your site, then do the upload to the remote site from your server, read the response, then relay the response back to the user.

Comment: Instead of grabbing the text file, could you just store the info in your database?

Comment: Interesting problem... if @webbiedave's *cURL* suggestions doesn't work, try the "JS version", AJAX. What would the response look like?

Comment: @ paul no because my server downt know the contents of the text file. is that the info that i want

Comment: ok, I misunderstood the question. In that case, it seems that the external site owners does NOT want anyone messing with the data it is returning. I hesitate going any further with this...

Comment: @AymanSafadi look the update there is the example of the response. it is exactly the same kind of response . i want my server to get the contents of that file that is downloaded to you when you submit uploading a pdf file

Comment: @Paul i dont think they dont want because is a FREE site but i think thay didnt think to this option

Comment: I don't think you can do this with AJAX (cc @AymanSafadi), though I should be happy to be proved wrong. But your larger problem is that whoever runs CoolUtils _could_ prevent access to their service if your client overuses it. Unless you have convincing information otherwise, I think this might be a risky stragegy for your client, as the service is prone to failure.

Comment: So: what are you actually trying to do? If you are converting a common format (JPG/PNG etc.) to PDF, try ImageMagick - it may well be installed on your host by default.

Comment: (I wouldn't trust that service much anyway: their spelling isn't great, and there's a PHP error on [this page](http://service.coolutils.com/PDF-Converter.php)).

Comment: maybe i found a partial solution because i won the "battle" to enable cURL but until now nothing changed also using curl it seems the file refuse to be posted correctly (problem of the encodin or of my code i dont know) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theory #2 would be the way to go. You could use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to post the data to the external site. The most likely obstacle preventing success would be the external site requiring cookie data that only the client would have.

Comment: i cant use cURL because it is not installed in my host provider and i cant do it because i have no access to the server

Comment: cURL disabled? Wow. That is rare. Time to find a new web host I would say.

Comment: hehe already paid for 2 years so i dont want to waste any other money of my client

Comment: @AlbiPatozi: you could use the browser classes in either SimpleTest or Lime (the test package for symfony 1.x) - both support cookies. However both are very likely to use curl internally, so are out for you unless you change hosts.

Comment: i enabled cURL by asking my host provider to chande the php.ini and they did this but still cant post the file corrrectly pfff i dont know why !

Comment: @Albi Patozi: Create a new question and include your new cURL code. You should be able to get help on solving that. In the meantime, please checkmark this question when you get a chance.